# How to draw items with rectangles and margin, in a vertically repeating ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I'm trying to visualize a `List<MyCustomClass>`.
Each item should be in a rectangle (with rounded corners, but that is another mattter), repeated vertically with a margin between the items.

I've tried this, but the items are overlapping:

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="CornflowerBlue" >

                    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Stroke="Blue" Width="350" Height="100">

                    </Rectangle>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Headline}" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="10" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDate}" Canvas.Left="55" Canvas.Top="40"/>
                    <Button Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click" Width="80" Height="25" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="20" />
                </Canvas>                            
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How can I fix this?
I guess the rectangle object itself is the wrong approach. Actually I thought the Canvas itself would be able to draw a background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Canvas` doesn't automatically size to the content it contains.  To do that you can use another layout element such as a `Grid`.  But a `Canvas` **is** convenient for laying out the position of children, as you have done.  As it is right now your `Canvas` has size `0,0` and that is why the `ItemsControl` panel is stacking them on top of each other.

If you want to continue to use a `Canvas`, then simply specify the size yourself, e.g.:

```
<Canvas Width="300" Height="100" ...>
```

or whatever values make sense for the right look.

If you switch to a `Grid`, then you can specify the position of children using the `Margin` property.  Note that a `Grid` without rows or columns by default stacks elements on top of each other, so it is very similar to a `Canvas` in that respect.  Just shift them using `Margin`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `ItemsPanel` template:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FeedItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ... etc ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```