# How to autosize container elements to ensure min-height for visibility issues?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, autosize

I have an ItemsControl and want to display some Strings from my CustomObject.

It's like

```
String A
String B
String C
```

where String A and B can be multiple lines long, but C can't. I was thinking of `Height="Auto"` and a DockPanel. The height of String A should be however it needs to be. With String B as well.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Black">
    <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF126eb1" BorderThickness="1.5" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" Background="#FF074e84" Width="350" Height="Auto">
                    <DockPanel Width="350" Margin="0,10,0,0" Height="Auto" Background="Transparent">
                        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="Auto" Width="350" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Headline}" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" MaxWidth="340" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto"/>
                        </Canvas>
                        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="Auto" Width="350" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="20" Foreground="White" FontSize="13" MaxWidth="340" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto" />
                        </Canvas>
                        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="350" Height="40" Margin="0,10,0,0" Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeadlineOn, StringFormat='Deadline: {0}'}" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5" Foreground="White"/>
                             <!-- and other controls -->
                        </Canvas>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Unfortunately only the margin property is making height for String A and B.

How can I do this, if the height of each item is unknown?

Comment: It's the same answer as your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481109/how-to-draw-items-with-rectangles-and-margin-in-a-vertically-repeating-itemscont/6481205#6481205.  Don't use a `Canvas` if you want it to auto-size.  Instead use a `Grid` and position child elements with a (possibly asymmetric) `Margin`.

Comment: @Rick Sladkey: Post as answer?

Comment: hmm yeah, you are right. Thanks. I guess I just got confused by all these container controls. For now I'll always remember that a Canvas can't autosize ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of layout elements and while this gives you a lot of choices, it can be hard to decide which layout element is the right one to use in any given situation.

In general, a `Canvas` is useful for its convenient fixed positioning capabilities.  It allows anything to be placed anywhere using the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties.  But because the size of a `Canvas` is fixed and doesn't depend on its children, it's difficult to use for variable-sized content.  The parent of the `Canvas` is "insulated" from the size of the children of the `Canvas`, and this is actually useful in some situations.

By contrast, a `Grid` is by far the flexible layout element and is useful for layout out grids with rows and columns, with or without spanning, etc.  This is why its the default when you create a new `Window` or `UserControl`.  But unlike a `Canvas`, the size of `Grid`, when unspecified and not stretched to the available space, is the union of the sizes of all its children.

A `Grid` also has the property that if it has several children and they aren't placed into rows or columns, then they are **overlayed** on top of each other, with later children being higher in the Z-order.  This is just like a `Canvas` but without `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`, how can we finely control the position of the children?

Let's look at an example.  Here is a `Canvas` with two rectangles placed side-by-side with a little space, and a `Grid` doing the same thing:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Canvas Height="120">
            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red"/>
            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="10" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Green"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Rectangle Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Rectangle Margin="120,10,10,10" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In the first case we had to specific the height of the `Canvas` because it doesn't auto-size.  In the second case, we used `Margin` to **simulate absolute positioning** and the `Grid` size adapts to the size of its content.